Getting this exception "AndroidJavaException : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Spliterator" How to resolve this?
Firebase crashlytics log:
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.Exception: AndroidJavaException : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Spliterator
       at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(libcore.reflect.InternalNames)
       at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(java.lang.Class)
       at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getDexCacheType(java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod)
       at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getReturnType(java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(java.lang.reflect.Method)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(java.lang.Class)
       at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper)
       at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke(com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper)
       at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.-$$Nest$smnativeProxyInvoke(com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper)
       at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$a.invoke(com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$a)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(java.lang.reflect.Proxy)
       at $Proxy16.onQueryPurchasesResponse($Proxy16)
       at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.zzaa(com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl)
       at com.android.billingclient.api.zzaa.run(com.android.billingclient.api.zzaa)
       at com.android.billingclient.api.zzu.run(com.android.billingclient.api.zzu)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Handler)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Handler)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(android.os.Looper)
       at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$F.run(com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$F)
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.ClassLoader)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.ClassLoader)
       at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(libcore.reflect.InternalNames)
       at classes.dex(classes)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(dalvik.system.DexFile)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(dalvik.system.DexFile)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(dalvik.system.DexFile)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(dalvik.system.DexFile)
       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(dalvik.system.DexPathList)
       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(dalvik.system.DexPathList)
       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(dalvik.system.DexPathList)
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader)
       at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(dalvik.system.PathClassLoader)
       at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.openArtFile(dalvik.system.PathClassLoader)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.reflect.Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.reflect.Method)
       at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.openArtFile(android.app.ApplicationLoaders)
       at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(android.app.ApplicationLoaders)
       at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(android.app.ApplicationLoaders)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(android.app.LoadedApk)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(android.app.LoadedApk)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(android.app.ActivityThread)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.app.ActivityThread$H)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Handler)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(android.os.Looper)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(android.app.ActivityThread)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.reflect.Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.reflect.Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit)
       at /data/app/com.madovergames.bubbleshooter.rainbow.game-1/arm/split_config.armeabi_v7a.odex(split_config.armeabi_v7a)
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.Class)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.BootClassLoader)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.BootClassLoader)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.ClassLoader)
       at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper)
       at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper)
       at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[ReturnType](UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper)
       at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[ReturnType](UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper)
       at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call[ReturnType](UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject)
       at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.Unbox(UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper)
       at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke(UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy)
       at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke(UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy)
       at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod(UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper)

We have added crashlytics to our android project but we are getting this non-fatal error.
Getting this exception at $Proxy16.onQueryPurchasesResponse ($Proxy16) this line.
Been trying to resolve this but so far no luck, any help would be appreciable.
